# How to add plugin to PhoneGap?

Tags: plugins, cordova

I'm confused a bit by PhoneGap documentation:

[Link 1](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features) // How add plugins using "phonegap local plugin add" command

[Link 2](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture) // Tutorial about how to use camera module

[Link 3](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using) // PhoneGap Plugins

I've added camera module according (1). But in (2), there is information saying that I should add

```
<plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
```

to `app/res/xml/plugins.xml` and edit `app/AndroidManifest.xml` files too.

In reference to 3), also there is information that `<plugin ... />` construction is obsolete and the developer should use `<gap:plugin ... />`, instead.

Answer (score 9):

Referencing the latest [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins) documentation:

There are two ways to approach this, first is by using Plugman, and the other is by using CLI. *The CLI approach is much simpler.*

**The Plugman approach:**

1. First, Plugman must be installed. Plugman is the plugin manager used by PhoneGap 3.4. To install Plugman, use the Node JS CLI and enter:

   `npm install -g plugman`
2. Install the specific plugin using the `plugman install` command. For example `plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin org.apache.cordova.device-motion`. Be sure that the parameter for the `--project` option points directly to the platform folder, e.g. for Android, that's where the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is. This command automatically adds all references to the plugins to the pertinent `xml` files.
3. Be sure that your `HTML` file references `phonegap.js` by the line `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>`.

**Using CLI:**

1. Go to your app directory and enter the plugin command in the CLI. For example:

   `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion`

   installs the accelerometer plugin.
2. After the plugin has installed, it automatically updates all `config.xml` by adding the corresponding `<feature>` tags. Note that these updates only affect the platform-specific `config.xml` files. And so, the top-level `config.xml` file is not affected. You must manually copy and paste the `<feature>` tags to the top level `config.xml`. Otherwise, the plugins will be disabled when you run the app using `phonegap run platform`.

Take note that the corresponding `<feature>` tags can only be added to the corresponding `config.xml` files if your project is already ready to deploy in that specific platform.

Comment: every single time i have to deal with javascript i wonder: how many package managers can you have? and the answer is always: one more!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using phonegap 3.0 the latest as of this answer, you add plugins from the command line like so.

"phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git"

This is supposed to then add all the references to the plugin automatically now.

Comment: `phonegap local plugin` is now deprecated, replaced by `phonegap plugin`

Answer (score 2):

I have recently installed the [AdMob](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin in my project.

To do this :

- I opened NODE.js command prompt.
- Navigated to the phonegap project.
- Then typed this into the cmd : `phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro`

This installed the plugin in the plugins directory in my phonegap project folder.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Since Phonegap 3.0 you need to use 'plugman' to add plugins to a phonegap project.The important part is to set the 'path' to your project in the platform specific project folder created by phonegap. In iOS it would be something like: /Users/user1/Dev/helloworld-phonegap/platforms/ios.

Do the following to install the dialogs plugin for ios.

1) npm install -g plugman
2) plugman install --platform ios --project /path/to/my/platform/folder --plugin org.apache.cordova.dialogs
I
check the docs for more info: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins