# Where/how are plug-ins in PhoneGap defined/set?

Tags: cordova, plugins

I've been following a lot of tutorials all over Google, but none of them seem to point to a singular, correct direction. The [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html) documentation mention setting of permissions to an XML file I can't find. [This](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins) documentation mentions a different story altogether.

I'm developing for **Android**, using the latest version as described [here](http://phonegap.com/install/), and using the `phonegap create app` command in the CLI, my `config.xml` file is located in `app\www\config.xml`.

**So where do I define my plug-ins and how? What's the correct syntax?** *I just want to work out how to use the accelerometer...*

[Here's](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html) another link with another story.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add plugin to PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922586/how-to-add-plugin-to-phonegap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the latest [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins) documentation:

There are two ways to approach this, first is by using Plugman, and the other is by using CLI. ***The CLI approach is much simpler.***

**The Plugman approach:**

1. First, Plugman must be installed. Plugman is the plugin manager used by PhoneGap 3.4. To install Plugman, use the Node JS CLI and enter:

   `npm install -g plugman`
2. Install the specific plugin using the `plugman install` command. For example `plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin org.apache.cordova.device-motion`. Be sure that the parameter for the `--project` option points directly to the platform folder, e.g. for Android, that's where the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is. This command automatically adds all references to the plugins to the pertinent `xml` files.
3. Be sure that your `HTML` file references `phonegap.js` by the line `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>`.

**Using CLI:**

1. Go to your app directory and enter the plugin command in the CLI. For example:

   `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion`

   installs the accelerometer plugin.
2. After the plugin has installed, it automatically updates all `config.xml` by adding the corresponding `<feature>` tags. Note that these updates only affect the platform-specific `config.xml` files. And so, the top-level `config.xml` file is not affected. You must manually copy and paste the `<feature>` tags to the top level `config.xml`. Otherwise, the plugins will be disabled when you run the app using `phonegap run platform`.

Take note that the corresponding `<feature>` tags can only be added to the corresponding `config.xml` files if your project is already ready to deploy in that specific platform.