# How to install a PhoneGap plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to install the splash screen plugin on PhoneGap. Do I just have to include

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
```

in my config.xml, or do I have to copy any files (which?) into the plugins folder, which is empty at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add plugin to PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922586/how-to-add-plugin-to-phonegap)

Comment: are you using phonegap build? then yes, that's enough