# PhoneGap - inappBrowser pluggin install/include

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I know there are a number of posts on how to use the functions of the cordova inapp browser pluggin and that's great. But I am having trouble installing or including the pluggin in my app when I upload it to PhoneGap Build.
When I include:

plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"

PhoneGap Build tells me that the pluggin is not supported...

I've also tried including the .git file but I couldn't get that working either. 
Im sure im just mistyping something or missing some step. Please help!!
All I need I'm sure is the correct plugin tag to use in my config file so if someone could just paste it in this thread that would be outstanding.

Comment: are you able to use command line installation ?

Comment: Does it work from mac/terminal?

Comment: If you one the command line prompt I am willing to try it...

Comment: yeah you can run it from MAC terminal

Comment: phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save Please run this command and change directory to your working directory .

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Then do I need to include the plugin tag on the config file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128731/discussion-between-hassan-ali-and-kyle-mathew-joeckel).

Comment: @KyleMathewJoeckel If phonegap command is not found, then your phonegap CLI is not installed properly. Check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922586/how-to-add-plugin-to-phonegap If you use cordova CLI, i will be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

So the issue I was having was because I did not install phonegap CLI before attempting to install the plugin. stupid me.... but I did it and got it working now! thanks for everyones input...

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap Build has dropped support for the old method of installing plugins. You now have to use NPM as the source.

Putting this in your `config.xml` should make it work on Phonegap Build:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />`